# Ember.js autofocus on just created template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible in Ember to set focus on just created template?

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
    {{#linkTo "foo.bars" class="success radius button"}}GET ALL THE BARS{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

How to set focus on the new `foo/bars` template?

Comment: What does "set focus" mean?

Comment: When I render new tour/seats template in the tour template's outlet, it does not fit on the screen so it need to scroll down to see tour/seats template. It seems I need to reorganize my templates, but this is not preferred way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `scrollIntoView`? You can create a view that calls that on its element after rendering:

```
App.FooFoo = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'foo',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var el = this.$()[0];
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
});
```